# Cannot install tensorflow (raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")

Tags: tensorflow

I don't know what is going on but I tried every thing possible already.

I installed stream-lit, and I create an app named app.py file and tried to deploy it.

Then I ran stream-lit run app.py to start the app at the local-server,

However, it keeps telling that the tensor flow library is required also.

So I tried to install Tensor flow using `pip3 install TensorFlow` or `pip install TensorFlow` but I'm keep getting this error:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading tensorflow-2.5.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (454.4 MB)
     |████████████▊                   | 180.3 MB 734 kB/s eta 0:06:14ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 519, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 458, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 502, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 180, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 204, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 318, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 127, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 473, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
    name, crit = self._merge_into_criterion(r, parent=None)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 172, in _merge_into_criterion
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 139, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 129, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 33, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 200, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 306, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 234, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 317, in _prepare_distribution
    return self._factory.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 508, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 550, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 239, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 102, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 157, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 152, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/utils.py", line 62, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 576, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 541, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Even with `pip install tensorflow` also:

```
pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading tensorflow-2.5.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (454.4 MB)
     |█████████████▌                  | 192.4 MB 1.2 MB/s eta 0:03:42ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 519, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 458, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 502, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 180, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 204, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 318, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 127, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 473, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
    name, crit = self._merge_into_criterion(r, parent=None)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 172, in _merge_into_criterion
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 139, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 129, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 33, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 200, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 306, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 234, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 317, in _prepare_distribution
    return self._factory.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 508, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 550, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 239, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 102, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 157, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 152, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/utils.py", line 62, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 576, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 541, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/streamlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

I don't get what is going on. I'm waiting for it to install and inform me of the completion of the installation so that I can move on with some actual ml project.

Please help

Comment: This could be a problem with your internet connection or the remote server, did you retry the installation process?

Comment: @user42493, Did you tried install again?

Comment: I solved, It was an internet problem, I then tried with a more stable internet connection and then it worked

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> This could be a problem with internet connection and successfully installed tensorflow with stable internet connection (paraphrased from Dr.Snoopy) .